# Open a webpage on a remote server using ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to open a webpage on a remote server using ansible. I've written a python code and am attempting to use it to open the website on the remote servers.
However I'm not able to do so even though ansible doesn't through any errors.
Here is the playbook:

```
---
- name: Executing script
  hosts: A


  tasks:
     - name: Running script
       command: python /home/usernname/web.py
```

Here is the python code

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Does the remote server have a browser installed?

Comment: Yes it does.In fact when i run this python code from the remote server it works fine.

Comment: maybe it just ran successfully? what makes you think that "you were not able to do so"

Comment: Because the browser  doesn't open up on the target host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using shell command to open that,something like xdg-open.Though that python code should work.
Btw are you using vnc to access the remote host?
If you are please check the remote host you're running this code on has display or export its display to the vnc client.I had the same issue and if you're using vnc then you will need to export display

Comment: I had the same issue.Glad to help